# Can I write several IDs in one document,

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I write several IDs in one document, for example

```
(document.getElementById("myDIV1" , "myDIV2").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: No, https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById ; you may have a look at libraries like jQuery for that kind of stuff

Answer (score 1):

No. `getElementById()` only takes a single id.

You could use `querySelectorAll()` instead though, you just need to loop through the result:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('#myDIV1, #myDIV2')
[].forEach.call(divs, function(div) {
  div.style.display = 'none';
});
```

Similarly, as you've tagged jQuery, you could use that:

```
$('#myDIV1, #myDIV2').hide();
```

Comment: And returns a single element, in case there are more elements with same id

Comment: @MarioNikolaus that's because you should never have multiple elements with the same `id`

Comment: @MarioNikolaus Which should never happen because IDs have to be unique

Comment: Yes, but that is in theory, there are a lot of people out there not knowing this.

Comment: @MarioNikolaus Returning multiple elements with the same ID was not the question.  It's easy to get around that, but is not related to *this* question (or answer).